# Certain users cannot connect to Apple Server through AFP

Tags: network, osx-server, afp, macos

I'm running into some issues with an Apple server running Server OS 10.4.11. There are 43 users in the workgroup manager, all with access to a RAID-server on that machine. Recently, a few of the users told me that they couldn't access it through their normal AFP process, however they can still access it through SMB. This is a temporary fix, as SMB is quite slow for them.

My testing was done on El Capitan 10.11.6. The users in question, let's call them $u1 and $u2, are running on Snow Leopard 10.6.8. AFP for $u1 and $u2's accounts does not work on their machines, nor mine. However, a newly created account works on AFP on their machines and mine.

I'm not sure what information I can provide in this situation, but so far, I've observed the following;

- I have reset that user's password, however the issue persists with AFP. Again, SMB has no issues connecting.
- When creating a new user on the server, they can connect with AFP just fine. A few existing users cannot. I have tried to compare settings between a new user and existing ones, but for all intents and purposes, things look the same.
- The Console gives me the following error when a login attempt fails:

  > NetAuthSysAgent: ERROR: AFP_OpenSession - login failed with 13

I can provide any other information that may be needed, this one is puzzling me to no end.

Comment: @IconDaemon Dropped an edit in there, forgot to mention that I did so, thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Server 10.4.11 (Tiger) is just shy of ten years old (last update Nov 14, 2007.) What macOS versions are running on your clients' machines? Could these problematic machines have a recent update?

Comment: @IconDaemon my testing was done on El Capitan. Other users are on a minimum standard of Yosemite.

Comment: So the Macs not capable of using AFP are running El Capitan? Please edit your question to indicate these particularities. :-)

Comment: @IconDaemon Information updated, thanks for your patience!

Comment: as a test, can you got to menu item /cmd-k **connect to server...** dialog and enter a user name manually to test.  ie:  afp://johndoe:@serveraddress/sharepoint .... hopefully it will just have these users changed passwords lately and they're cached or keychained?   -- also how are they initiating connections (shortcuts, cmd-k, browsing...)?